# Webservice in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a beginner with **hyperledger composer**. I want to use webservice API for request/response json inside JavaScript Transaction. it is possible or not? if you have any examples with this please tell me. Thank in advance!

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "gender": "string"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using request-promise module which is availabe to all transaction processor functions via the request global variable. You do not need to add the request or request-promise modules to your package.json file, nor do you need to use the require function to load the modules.

The global request method and all of the convenience methods for the various HTTP methods (request.get, request.post, etc.) are available to transaction processor functions. These methods provide a full set of options for handling request bodies, response bodies, HTTP headers, authentication, cookies, proxies, and TLS/SSL.

Eg:

```
/**
 * Buy a given amount of CONGA stocks.
 * @param {org.example.BuyStocks} transaction The transaction.
 * @transaction
 */
async function buyStocks(transaction) {

    // Look up the current price of the CONGA stock, and parse it into a float.
    const priceAsStr = await request.get('http://stocks.org/CONGA');
    const price = parseFloat(priceAsStr);

    // Get the current participant, and update their stock and balance.
    const participant = getCurrentParticipant();
    const units = transaction.units;
    participant.stockUnits += units;
    participant.balance -= price * units;

    // Update the current participant in the participant registry.
    const participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.Trader');
    await participantRegistry.update(participant);

}
```

Visit [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/integrating/call-out.html) for reference